Force of a tensioned rope on an obstructing block.
I would like some help solving this problem. I tried to present this in the physics forum but the support in there for tables isn't as good as here. If you look at the diagram below, i'm trying to discover the force applied by the rope onto the obstructing block.
Can someone follow along to see if I did this right?
Consider $T_4$ to be colinear with the y-axis.
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
& \text{x-component} & \text{y-component} \\
\hline
T_1 & -T_1\cos(70) & T_1\sin(70) \\
T_2 & \; T_2\cos(80) & T_2\sin(80) \\
T_4 & 0 & 980
\end{array}
$$


Now look for further working underneath this diagram.

$$\sum F_x = -T_1\cos(70) + T_2\cos(80) = 0 \qquad \qquad (1)$$
$$\sum F_y = T_1\sin(70) + T_2\sin(80) -980 = 0 \qquad \, (2)$$


Considering equation (1).
$$
\begin{align}
T_2\cos(80) &= T_1\cos(70) \\
T_2 &= \frac{T_1\cos(70)}{\cos(80)} \\
T_2 &= 1.9696T_1
\end{align}
$$
Considering equation (2)
$$
\begin{align}
T_1\sin(70) + T_2\sin(80) &= 980 \\
T_1\sin(70) + 1.9696T_1\sin(80) &= 980 \\
T_1(\sin(70) + 1.9696\sin(80)) &= 980 \\
T_1 &= \frac{980}{\sin(70) + 1.9696\sin(80)} \\
T_1 &= 340.3504 \, \text{N} \\
T_2 &= 1.9696T_1 \\
T_2 &= 1.9696 \times 340.3504 \, \text{N} \\
T_2 &= 670.3595 \, \text{N}
\end{align}
$$
So now to establish $T_3$ and the force applied onto the obstructing block, I form the triangle with obtuse angle $176^o$. Where I have put the $176^o$ is where the obstructing block corner is.

Using Cosine Rule to find the triangle.
$$
\begin{align}
a^2 &= b^2 + c^2 - 2bc\cos(A) \\
a^2 &= 36 + 4 - 2(6)(2)\cos(176) \\
a^2 &= 63.9415 \\
a &= 7.9963 \, \text{m}
\end{align}
$$
Using Sine Rule to establish other angles of the triangle.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{6}{\sin(B)} &= \frac{7.9963}{\sin(176)}  \\
\sin(B) &= \frac{6 \sin(176)}{7.9963} \\
B &= \arcsin(0.0523) \\
B & = 3^o \\
C &= 1^o
\end{align}
$$
Now, I believe $F_{block}$ is perpendicular to the long side of the triangle (7.9963 side). If we rotate the triangle so that $F_{block}$ is colinear with y-axis and long side is parallel to x-axis we have.
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
& \text{x-component} & \text{y-component} \\
\hline
T_2 & 670.3595\cos(1) & 6670.3595\sin(1) \\
T_3 & \; -T_3\cos(3) & T_3\sin(3) \\
F_{block} & 0 & -670.3595\sin(1) - T_3\sin(3)
\end{array}
$$


$$\sum F_x = -T_3\cos(3) + 670.3595\cos(1) = 0 \qquad \qquad (1)$$


$$
\begin{align}
T_3 &= \frac{670.3595\cos(1)}{\cos(3)}  \\
T_3 &= 671.1772 \, \text{N} 
\end{align}
$$


$$
\begin{align}
F_{block} &= -670.3595\sin(1) - T_3\sin(3)  \\
F_{block} &= -46.8261 \, \text{N} 
\end{align}
$$


To relate to this in a real-world sense, $F=mass \times gravity$.
$$
\begin{align}
46.8261\, \text{N} &= mass \times 9.8 \, \text{m/s^2}  \\
mass &= \frac{46.8261}{9.8} \\
mass &= 4.7781 \, kg 
\end{align}
$$
The force applied on the block from the rope, 46.8261 Newtons, is about equivalent to the force required to pick up a 5kg dumbell.

Are you assuming that the contact between the rope and the obstructing block is frictionless? In which case, $T_2=T_3$.

@DavidQuinn aaaahhhh, thankyou. I was assuming it was frictionless and you have answered the main point of my question. I didn't know how to treat $T_2$ and $T_3$. I did a sample question where a bird landed in the middle of a 50m telephone cable and the tension was equal on both sides of the bird. Would the tension be equal on both sides of the bird if it landed one quarter the way from right pole instead of halfway?

Yes it would as long as the contact is frictionless

@DavidQuinn sorry to ask more questions as I still need more clarification. So how come we establish $T_1$ and $T_2$ as not equal? Is it not similar to a bird not landing in the middle of the rope anchors? I'm sure i'm missing something here? I'm assuming a knot between $T_1$ and $T_2$. Would I have to assume a pulley with the load attached to it instead of a knot to have both tensions equal?

$T_1$ and $T_2$ would be equal if they were one continuous rope (or two knotted together) with the load rope $T_4$ attached by means of a smooth ring or pulley which is free to move along the rope. In that case they would both make equal angles with the vertical.

BTW the reaction at the block must bisect the angle between the two sides of the rope in contact.

Ok, thanks for your help @DavidQuinn

The comment, BTW the reaction at the block must bisect the angle between the two sides of the rope in contact. is there because there is only one force due to the corner acting on the rope - normal force. The sum of the components of the equal tensions on either side of the corner must equal the normal force and since the tensions are equal that means that the two angles between the normal and the tensions must be the same. Put another way, the components of the tensions at right angles to the normal add up to zero.
